# How to compute the tensor product $[0,1] \times [2,k]$ in $SP(4)$?

Tags: symmetry, tensor-calculus, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra

In this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.01862) the authors give in eq.(A.4) the tensor product $[0,a] \otimes [0,b]$, with $[a,b]$ the Dynkin labels for irreps of $SP(4)$. How can one compute the tensor product $[0,1] \otimes [2,k]$, e.g. for the case $k=0$ if it is too cumbersome to go above? I am rubbish in group theory and I don't even know where to start.

Comment: Can you please clarify if you're talking about unirreps of $Sp(4,\mathbb{R})$ (the non-compact) or $Sp(4)_C$, the compact complexification (finite dimensional non-unitary irreps of the real form)?  I believe $\mathfrak{sp}(4)$ is basically $\mathfrak{so}(5)$ and this can be found in the literature.  Tensoring and decomposing unirreps of the non-compact real form is *quite* another matter and gives an infinite sum (certainly not A.4).  They do mention the non-compact $\mathfrak{so}(2,1)\sim \mathfrak{sp}(2,\mathbb{R})$ in there...

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Yes sorry I am interested in $\mathfrak{so}(5)$ indeed. Hope this clarifies, I am not sure regarding the rest of your message to be honest.

Comment: Do you need generic k in $[2,k]$ or specific values?

Comment: Immediately I need $k=0$, I suspect that I will need higher $k$ after that though. The exact values will depend on the result of $[0,1] \times [2,0]$ actually!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like
\begin{align}
[0,1]\otimes[2,0]= [2,1]\oplus [1,1]\, .
\end{align}
For specific values of the indices there is [this nice web interface to LiE](http://www-math.univ-poitiers.fr/%7Emaavl/LiE/form.html) hosted at the Université de Poitiers.  From the dropdown menu select "Tensor product decomposition" and then B2 for the type of simple group since $\mathfrak{so}(5)\sim\mathfrak{sp}(4)$ is B2 in the Cartan classification.

Now, $\mathfrak{sp}(4)$ and $\mathfrak{so}(5)$ are isomorphic but conventionally the long and short roots are interchanged so it might be that $[0,1]\otimes [2,0]$ in $\mathfrak{sp}(4)$ could actually be $[1,0]\otimes[0,2]$ in $\mathfrak{so}(5)$, which decomposes (differently) as
\begin{align}
[1,0]\otimes[0,2]= [1,2]\oplus [0,2]\oplus [1,0]\, .
\end{align}
Moreover, the convention on the ordering of Dynkin labels can be author dependent so you should check some cases by hand (*i.e.* get a list of weights for your irreps, which LiE can also do) for proper interpretation of the output.

Comment: Oh so *that*'s why everything gets reversed when using $so_5=sp_2$!! I've been wondering this since forever. Thanks :-)

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform yes that's somewhat quirky.   If you look at the tensorial structure of the $\mathfrak{sp}(2n,\mathbb{R})$ raising and lowering operators (w/r to the maximal $\mathfrak{u}(n)$ subalgebra) as a function of $n$, it would work out to an interchange of long and short root vectors w/r to $\mathfrak{so}(5)$ in the rank-2 case.

Comment: Amazing, thanks for the nice link! In my notation above the shorts correspond to $[0,k]$, while the $[2,0]$ are semi-shorts. Does that correspond to the second expression in your answer then?

Comment: Oh I just saw the last sentence of your post, yeah I guess I'll figure it out!